# Python - multiprocessing join() does not work as expected?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
.
.
.
iouThresholds = np.array([0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95], dtype=np.float64)
.
.
.
processes = []
for iou_threshold in iouThresholds:
    process = Process(target=save_ap, args=(gt_data, predictions, class_names, iou_threshold, output_dir))
    processes.append(process)
# end for

for process in processes:
    process.start()
# end for

for process in processes:
    process.join()
    print('joined save_ap process')
# end for

# get overall metrics
metric, overall_ap = get_metric_overall_ap(iouThresholds, output_dir, class_names)
```

The function `get_metric_overall_ap` will crash if it is ran before the 10 processes are finished.  Unfortunately that is what is happening.  How can this be?  As far as I can tell, the for loop with the `process.join()` should hold execution at that point until all 10 processes are done, correct?  What am I missing here?  Is there anything else I should check?

One additional odd thing I should mention is that I'm running this on two computers, one is recent and top spec, the other was top spec when I got it about 3.5 years ago but it's somewhat dated now.  When I run identical code with identical inputs, the crash only happens on the older machine.  Also I can mention that the crash happens every time on the older machine, usually 8 of the 10 processes finish as of when `get_metric_overall_ap` is called, resulting in the crash.  Is this helpful in diagnosing what I'm doing wrong somehow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In case more context would be helpful, here is `save_ap`:

```
def save_ap(gt, predictions, class_names, iou_threshold, output_dir):
    print('calling save_ap with iou_threshold = ' + str(iou_threshold))
    ap = get_average_precisions(gt, predictions, class_names, iou_threshold)

    metric = dict()
    for idx, class_name in enumerate(class_names):
        metric[class_name] = ap[idx]
    # end for

    print('\n' + 'type(metric) = ' + str(type(metric)))
    print('len(metric) = ' + str(len(metric)))
    pprint.pprint(metric)

    summary_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'metric_summary_' + str(iou_threshold) + '.json')
    with open(str(summary_path), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(metric, f)
    # end with
# end function
```

here is `get_metric_overall_ap`:

```
def get_metric_overall_ap(iouThresholds, output_dir, class_names):
    metric = {}
    overall_ap = np.zeros(len(class_names))
    for iou_threshold in iouThresholds:
        summary_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'metric_summary_' + str(iou_threshold) + '.json')
        with open(str(summary_path), 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            metric[iou_threshold] = data
            overall_ap += np.array([data[c] for c in class_names])
        # end with
    # end for

    overall_ap /= len(iouThresholds)
    return metric, overall_ap
# end function
```

Here is terminal output before and during the error:

```
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.5
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.55
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.6
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.65
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.7
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.75
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.8
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.85
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.9
calling save_ap with iou_threshold = 0.95

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 3.7443086508507067e-06,
 'bus': 1.002977713768843e-05,
 'car': 0.010691507156393068,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.003852912497013441,
 'pedestrian': 3.516885446248802e-08,
 'truck': 0.0}

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.006926153810066134,
 'bus': 0.007049050976195909,
 'car': 0.33458208718146915,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.16603585785752553,
 'pedestrian': 0.0005913558211640129,
 'truck': 3.7931358232921774e-05}

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.05471397633671474,
 'bus': 0.026556849828527223,
 'car': 0.46218537679028665,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.27988719269234963,
 'pedestrian': 0.0029712071830179363,
 'truck': 6.152806608895385e-05}
joined save_ap process

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.0,
 'bus': 0.0,
 'car': 5.7046485300735835e-06,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 2.065499466688038e-07,
 'pedestrian': 0.0,
 'truck': 0.0}

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.002161123295596573,
 'bus': 0.0036830620561412127,
 'car': 0.24377507162930123,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.11502473189077161,
 'pedestrian': 0.00015325871767874713,
 'truck': 3.299011321141335e-05}

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.027986554965107904,
 'bus': 0.01578852743093585,
 'car': 0.41108810168462295,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.2350665650793733,
 'pedestrian': 0.0017521481677343154,
 'truck': 5.954302699985434e-05}
joined save_ap process
joined save_ap process
joined save_ap process
joined save_ap process

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.00012716150741225055,
 'bus': 0.0001940839763015727,
 'car': 0.05609662328088803,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.021352198392924612,
 'pedestrian': 1.5919676084972234e-06,
 'truck': 3.299011321141335e-05}
joined save_ap process
joined save_ap process
joined save_ap process
joined save_ap process

type(metric) = <class 'dict'>
len(metric) = 9
{'animal': 0.0,
 'bicycle': 0.0,
 'bus': 0.0,
 'car': 0.0,
 'emergency_vehicle': 0.0,
 'motorcycle': 0.0,
 'other_vehicle': 0.0,
 'pedestrian': 0.0,
 'truck': 0.0}
joined save_ap process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2_train.py", line 561, in <module>
    main()
  File "2_train.py", line 348, in main
    evalDataset.evaluation_lyft(detections, result_path_step)
  File "/home/cdahms/workspace-av/lyft-3d-det/my_lyft_dataset.py", line 502, in evaluation_lyft
    metric, overall_ap = get_metric_overall_ap(iouThresholds, output_dir, class_names)
  File "/home/cdahms/workspace-av/lyft-3d-det/my_lyft_dataset.py", line 601, in get_metric_overall_ap
    with open(str(summary_path), 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/cdahms/workspace-av/lyft-3d-det/results/step_18144/metric_summary_0.7.json'
```

The error is happening specifically because `get_metric_overall_ap` is attempting to read the 10 files that should have been written by the 10 calls to `save_ap` but since at least one of the files hasn't been written yet, it crashes.

Comment: Add `print('done writing ' + summary_path)` at the end of `save_ap` function

Comment: just adding and I'm running again, it takes about 1.5 hours to reach the crash though

Comment: Ohh, in that case, you can considering writing some dummy constant json data to the files by commenting cpu code and see if you are able to reproduce the issue. How big are the files and disk configuration/OS? I'm wondering if the RAID level of the disk can cause a file which was just written to not being able to be read for very small `x` milliseconds. So another suggestion would be to say sleep for a second after the joins finish before you execute the `get_metric_overall_ap`.

Comment: I'm not using RAID, the files are small (< 1000 bytes), and I have plenty of disk space.  Should I put a 1 second sleep after the file write in save_ap?  I think I'm going to try that.

Comment: I just put a 1 second sleep after the file write in save_ap, running again, in about 1.5 hours I'll know if that resolved it.

Comment: You should also put the `with open(str(summary_path), 'r') as f:` in `get_metric_overall_ap` into a try/except block and log the error, to ensure that you only see the issue for a single file, and even if a particular file is missing you would log the error and move on to the remaining files.

Comment: Yeah.  I strongly suspect that one of your processes is getting an error that you're not seeing, and that the file you thing is being written isn't.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what's happening here. The join() will **NOT** return unless and until the associated Process has ended. Your problem is simply that the file that you expected to exist hasn't been created. I suggest you *wrap* the entire functionality of *save_ap* in a try/except block then print the exception (because I'm certain that's what's happening). Either *get_average_precisions* (which we can't see) is raising an exception **or** your *ap* list has fewer elements than your *class_names* list.

Comment: Also, please consider using ProcessPoolExecutor. You may be thrashing your system by creating too many Processes and that may account for the extended duration of the overall task

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that if the sleep doesn't help.  If one of the processes is erroring out, are you saying I wouldn't see an error for it on the terminal?

Comment: @cdahms some IDE's don't handle stdout and stderr from child processes perfectly (particularly some versions of IPython), so yes it is not uncommon for exception and traceback of child to be missed. afaik, system terminal (cmd on windows, terminal on mac, bash/etc on linux) almost always gets it right. Also using `mp.Pool` or `concurrent.futures` executor attempts to do error handling, which makes you go looking for the error rather than just printing it out.